# Select All childrens in all levels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an script as following:

```
$('.Addable').find('input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('name')) {
                var Name = $(this).attr('name');
                var Number = Name;
                if (Name.substring(Name.length - 1) == ']') {
                    var Fi = Name.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
                    var Li = Name.lastIndexOf("]");
                    if (Fi > -1) {
                        Number = Name.substring(Fi, Li);
                        if (Number > Indx) {
                            Number = Number - 1;
                            $(this).attr('name', Name.substring(0, Fi) + Number + ']');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

So that change Name of `input`s perfectly, nut now I need to change all elements not only `input`s like `select`s I think to Replace first line with:

```
$('.Addable').children().each(function () {
```

But that not worked, so what is your suggestion to select all child elements?

Comment: what is the HTML of this? what is the scope when you say "all"? all descendants?

Comment: @Joseph. all === all :), just kiding he probably doesn't really want them **all**.

Comment: Please use camel case for variables.

Comment: @gdoron: is it really our place to comment on code style?

Comment: @DavidHedlund. Yes... If it helps the OP, why not?

Comment: @DavidHedlund. This is the standard  most js developrs use... If it bothers you I can delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ALL descendent elements, you can do what @gdoron suggested. If you're looking for all form fields in general, not just `input`'s, you can use the `:input` selector, which will also match `select`, `textarea`, etc.:

```
$('.Addable').find(':input').each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Can't you just write `$('.Addable:input').each(...);` ?

Comment: Close. `$('.Addable :input').each(...);` (you need the space).

Answer (score 2):

> So what is your suggestion to select all child elements?

**Options:**

```
$('.Addable *').each(function () {
$('.Addable').find('*').each(function () {
```

`jQuery('*')` [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements.
>   *Caution: The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself.*